# Why does attribute splitting happen in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I try to get the attribute of the parent element:

```html
<div class="detailMS__incidentRow incidentRow--away odd">
    <div class="time-box">45'</div>
    <div class="icon-box soccer-ball-own"><span class="icon soccer-ball-own">&nbsp;</span></div>
    <span class=" note-name">(Autogoal)</span><span class="participant-name">
        <a href="#" onclick="window.open('/player/reynaldo/CxtEEPzE/'); return false;">Reynaldo</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

```py
span_autogoal = soup.find('span', class_='note-name')
print(span_autogoal)
print(span_autogoal.find_parent('div')['class'])
# print(span_autogoal.find_parent('div').get('class')
```

Output:

```
<span class="note-name">(Autogoal)</span>
['detailMS__incidentRow', 'incidentRow--away', 'odd']
```

I know i can do something like this:

```py
print(' '.join(span_autogoal.find_parent('div')['class']))
```

But i want to know why this is happening and is it possible to do this more correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `BeautifulSoup` [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes):

> HTML 4 defines a few attributes that can have multiple values. HTML 5
>   removes a couple of them, but defines a few more. The most common
>   multi-valued attribute is class (that is, a tag can have more than one
>   CSS class). Others include rel, rev, accept-charset, headers, and
>   accesskey. **Beautiful Soup presents the value(s) of a multi-valued
>   attribute as a list**:

```
css_soup = BeautifulSoup('<p class="body"></p>') css_soup.p['class']
# ["body"]

css_soup = BeautifulSoup('<p class="body strikeout"></p>')
css_soup.p['class']
# ["body", "strikeout"]
```

So in your case in `<div class="detailMS__incidentRow incidentRow--away odd">` a `class` attribute is *multi-valued*.

That's why `span_autogoal.find_parent('div')['class']` gives you `list` as an output.

Answer (score 2):

Above answer is correct however if you want get mutli attribute value return as string try use `xml` parser after get the parent element.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data='''<div class="detailMS__incidentRow incidentRow--away odd">
    <div class="time-box">45'</div>
    <div class="icon-box soccer-ball-own"><span class="icon soccer-ball-own">&nbsp;</span></div>
    <span class=" note-name">(Autogoal)</span><span class="participant-name">
        <a href="#" onclick="window.open('/player/reynaldo/CxtEEPzE/'); return false;">Reynaldo</a>
    </span>
</div>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
span_autogoal = soup.find('span', class_='note-name')
print(span_autogoal)
parentdiv=span_autogoal.find_parent('div')

data=str(parentdiv)

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'xml')
print(soup.div['class'])
```

Output on console:

```
<span class="note-name">(Autogoal)</span>
detailMS__incidentRow incidentRow--away odd
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to explore bs4 4.7.1